# SqlException: Invalid object name 'Usuari'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Estoy intentando mostrar una vista con la lista de usuarios pero cuando voy a la vista me devuelve este error: [image: Error aplicación]

Tengo la cadena de conexion a la DB en appsettings.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=XXXX\\XXXX;Initial Catalog=GUS;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

En mi startup.cs tengo esto:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<GusContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

En mi controlador, esto:

```
 public class UsuarisController : Controller
{
    private readonly GusContext _context;

    public UsuarisController(GusContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Usuaris
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Usuaris.ToListAsync());
    }
```

El modelo Usuari.cs es este:

```
namespace Gus.Models
{
public class Usuaris
{
    [Key]
    public int idUsuari { get; set; }
    public string samlString { get; set; }
    public string mail { get; set; }
    public string nom { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UsuarisCentres> UsuarisCentres { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Rols> Rols { get; set; }
}
}
```

El GusContext este:

```
using Gus.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Gus.Data
{
public class GusContext : DbContext
{
    public GusContext(DbContextOptions<GusContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<lkCentres> Centres { get; set; }
    public DbSet<lkInstitucions> Institucions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Rols> Rols { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Usuaris> Usuaris { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UsuarisCentres> UsuarisCentres { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<lkCentres>().ToTable("Centre");
        modelBuilder.Entity<lkInstitucions>().ToTable("Institucio");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Rols>().ToTable("Rol");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuaris>().ToTable("Usuari");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UsuarisCentres>().ToTable("UsuariCentre");
    }
}
}
```

Y finalmente la vista recibe un IEnumerable de Gus.Models.Usuaris y un foreach me debería de printa una tabla.

A ver si me podéis echar una mano, soy bastante novatillo y ando un poco perdido.

Gracias!

Comment: Has comprobado si la cadena de conexión es correcta? o que en vez de usuari es usuaris lo que tienes que invocar?

Comment: Mira el nombre de la tabla que se creo en la base de datos. Debería ser `"Usuari"`. Sin **s**.

Comment: Me parece que el modelo debería llamarse `Usuaris.cs` y no `Usuari.cs`, puede que el *`Invalid object name`* que estás teniendo se deba a eso. Tienes que ser coherente en la nominación de tus archivos, objetos, columnas, variables...

Comment: @NicolasOñate La cadena de conexión entiendo que es correcta, como lo podría comprobar?

Comment: @A.Cedano Correcto mi modelo se llama Usuaris, me he equivocado al escribirlo.

Comment: @MarcVidalSolsona Puedes comprobarla usando el SQL Manager, como tienes en la etiqueta, doy por supuesto que estas usando sql-server, ahi escribes las credenciales y ves si puedes acceder a la BBDD

Comment: Trata quitando esta linea de GusContext `Entity<Usuaris>().ToTable("Usuari");`

Comment: Bueno, al final era tema de permisos del usuario que me habían dado para conectarme a la BD. 
Gracias por la ayuda!